# Easier way for use SQLite in Phonegap

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova

I need use `SQLite` in my `Phonegap` application, but I'm new in `Phonegap`

What is easier way for work `SQLite` in `Phonegap`?

My application is focused for Android device

Comment: go for websql.. PhoneGap supports websql

Comment: Websql is look like https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this plugin `https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage`. This is supported by phonegap build also. Refer how to use and limitations section before using it.

If you are planning to use phonegap builds and need any other alternative plugins visit https://build.phonegap.com/plugins and search for sqlite plugins.